# setnamedsecurityinfo works great on Win7 x64, fails on Win7 x86

Tags: c#, windows-7, pinvoke, 32bit-64bit

The following method works fine on Win7 Pro SP1 x64, but when I run it on Win7 Pro SP1 x86 it fails when it gets to the //write the new owner comment

What are some reasons why it would work on one and not the other?

This is using pinvoke

thanks!

```
public static void ChangeOwner(ref string strPath, string strUserName)
    {
        IntPtr pNewOwner = default(IntPtr);
        IntPtr deUse = default(IntPtr);
        Win32Exception Win32Error = default(Win32Exception);
        string domain_name = null;
        int ret = 0;
        int sid_len = 0;
        int domain_len = 0;

        // Series of quick sanity checks before we proceed...

        //Do we have the required Privilege?
        if (SetPrivileges() == false)
        {
            throw new Exception("Required privilege not held by the user");
        }

        // Convert the name to a valid SID
        sid_len = SID_SIZE;
        pNewOwner = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(sid_len);
        domain_len = NAME_SIZE;
        string domainThing = "";
        domain_name = domainThing.PadRight(domain_len);
        if (LookupAccountName(null, strUserName, pNewOwner, ref sid_len, domain_name, ref domain_len, ref deUse) == false)
        {
            ret = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
            Win32Error = new Win32Exception(ret);
            //throw new Exception(Win32Error.Message);
        }

        // write the new Owner
        ret = SetNamedSecurityInfo(strPath, SE_FILE_OBJECT, OWNER_SECURITY_INFORMATION, pNewOwner, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
        if (ret != 0)
        {
            Win32Error = new Win32Exception(ret);
            throw new Exception(Win32Error.Message);
        }

        // clean up and go home
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pNewOwner);
    }
```

Comment: During Debugging, I notice that on my Win7x64 installation, pNewOwner = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(sid_len); that pNewOwner = 451442928 but on my Win7x86 install, I get a NullArgumentException

Comment: You need to show how you define the p/invoked function

Comment: This question is pointless without the p/invoke declarations. One plausible explanation is that you used the wrong calling convention which would have an impact on x86, but not on x64. But there are loads of other explanations.